# To Continuously loop using for in shell scripting

Tags: shell

```
for m in $count
  do
        `cat $op ${arr[$m]} > $op1`
        `rm -f $op`
        `touch $op`
        `cat $op1 ${arr[$m+1]} > $op`
        if [ $m ge $count ]; then
        `rm -f $op1`
        `touch $op1`
        fi
        m=$((m+1))
  done
```

I wanted to continuously loop from the start count 2 till the end count 10 . The  $count=10 here. But the above piece of code executes the for loop only once.

Comment: Do you really have that many backquotes in your script, or was that an attempt to get the code looking like code?  To get code, write it as you'd like to see it, then select it, and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box — but you've been around long enough you should know that. The code as written will 'work', but only because Unix commands are silent on success and all the commands will generate no standard output, so the backticks execute an empty command, but that's plain perverse as a way of writing shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rainy sunday - having much free time - long answer ;)

Many issues with your script, some recommended solutions. Because you used the construction `m=$((m+1))` - will be using `bash` as "shell". (Consider adding the `bash` tag)

For the cycle - several possibilities

```
count=10
m=2                           #start with 2
while (( $m <= $count ))      #while m is less or equal to 10
do                            #do
        echo $m               #this action
        let m++               #increment m (add one to m)
done                          #end of while
```

or, if the count is a constant (not a variable), you can write

```
for m in {2..10}    #REMEMBER, will not works with a variables, like  {2..$count}
do
    echo "$m"
done
```

another variant - using the `seq` ([man seq](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/9base-seq.1.html)) command for counting

```
for m in $(seq 2 ${count:=10})  # ${count:=10} - defaults the $count to 10 if it is undefined
do
    echo $m
done
```

or C-like for loop

```
let count=10
for ((m=2; m<=count; m++))
do
        echo $m
done
```

All 4 loops produces:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

so, having a right cycle now. Now add your specific actions.

The:

```
rm -f $op
touch $op
```

can be replaced by one command

```
echo -n > $op  #echo nothing and write the "nothing" into the file
```

it is faster, because the `echo` is an [bash *builtin*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) (doesn't start two external commands)

So your actions could looks like

```
cat $op ${arr[$m]} > $op1
echo -n > $op
cat $op1 ${arr[$m+1]} > $op
```

in this case, the `echo` is useless, because the second `cat` will write its output
to the $op anyway (and before write shortens the file to zero size), so this result is
identical with the above

```
cat $op ${arr[$m]} > $op1
cat $op1 ${arr[$m+1]} > $op
```

Those two `cat` commands can be shorted to one, using bash's `>>` append to file redirection

```
cat ${arr[$m]} ${arr[m+1]} >> $op
```

The whole script could look like the next

```
#making a testing environment

for f in $(seq 12)               #create 12 files opdata-N 
do
    arr[$f]="opdata-$f"          #store the filenames in the array "arr"
    echo "data-$f" > ${arr[$f]}  #each file contains one line "data-N"
done
#echo ${arr[@]}

#setting the $op and $op1 filenames
#consider choosing more descriptive variable names
op="file_op"
#op1="file_op1"   #not needed

#add some initial (old) value to $op
echo "initial value" > $op
#end of creating the testing environment

#the script
count=10
for m in $(seq 2 $count)
do
    cat ${arr[$m]} ${arr[m+1]} >> $op   
done
```

at the end, file `$op` will contain:

```
initial value
data-2
data-3
data-3
data-4
data-4
data-5
data-5
data-6
data-6
data-7
data-7
data-8
data-8
data-9
data-9
data-10
data-10
data-11
```

BTW, are you sure about the result? Because if only want add `file-2` .. `file-10` to the end of `$op` (without duplicating entries), you can simple write:

```
cat file-{2..10} >> $op    #the '>>' adds to the end of file...
```

or by using your array:

```
startpos=2
count=10
cat ${arr[@]:$startpos:$count} >> $op
```

Ufff.. ;)

Ps: usually it is good practice to enclose variables in double quotes like `"$filename"` - in the above examples for better readability I omitted them.

Comment: Very useful answer. I would upvote twice if I could. Productive use of a Sunday!

Comment: Nicely done; a shorter and possibly more portable alternative to `echo -n > $op` is to use the `:` builtin `: > $op`.

Answer (score 1):

Any loop needs a "condition to keep looping". When you use a

```
for m in count
```

type of loop, the condition is "if there are more elements in the collection `count`, pick the next one and keep going". This doesn't seem to be what you want. You are looking for the `bash` equivalent of

```
for(m = 0; m < 10; m++)
```

I think. The best way to do this is - with exactly that kind of loop (but note - an extra pair of parentheses, and a semicolon):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Display message 5 times
for ((i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)); do
  echo "Welcome $i times."
done
```

[see nix craft for original](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-applesox-bsd-bash-cstyle-for-loop/)

I think you can extend this to your situation… if I understood your question correctly you need something like this:

```
for ((m = 2; m <= 10; m++))
  do
    cat $op ${arr[$m]} > $op1
    rm -f $op
    touch $op
    cat $op1 ${arr[$m+1]} > $op
    if [ $m ge $count ]; then
      rm -f $op1
      touch $op1
    fi
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop instead.

The for loop is when you have multiple objects to iterate against. You have only one, i.e. $count.